# How can I get regex to validate php addslashes() characters (specifically apostrophe)

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to validate a string (a name) using preg_match(). I am passing in a string called $lname which is a string containing an apostrophe which has been slashed. An example of this is "O\'Neill". I have tried multiple regex layouts and solutions for this including (\') , \' , and just '. It does not work and give a true output being valid. Can anyone offer a solution.

Here is my code:

```
$lname = "O\'Neill";
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\'\s-]+$/",$lname))
    echo "valid";
```

Comment: I see two solutions: 1) accept \ in the regex pattern ; 2) remove \ from your string before testing the regex.

Comment: You have to escate the slash with double slash so instead you have to use `[a-zA-Z\\'\s-]+`

Comment: If you want to allow the slash only before the apostrophe, use `^([a-zA-Z\s-]|\\?')+$`

Comment: You just need `"/^[a-zA-Z\\\\'\s-]+$/"`. Better - `"/^[a-zA-Z\\\\'\s-]+\z/"`. Shorter - `"/^[A-Z\\\\'\s-]+\z/i"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that would match O'Neil not just O\'Neil

Comment: @Devon Exactly what is necessary. Right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Possibly, I thought from the first read they don't want to match O'Neil as a way of ensuring slashes were added, but maybe I misunderstood the requirements.

Comment: @Devon The question is rather poorly worded. Let Alex explain. Alex?

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is not escaping the backslash.  You'd need to write a literal backslash as `\\` in regex.

However, if you just do that, you'd be looking for a backslash or apostrophe anywhere, not a sequential `\'` because of your `[...]` which matches any character inside.

The correct way to do this would be to look for it outside of the brackets.

```
^([a-zA-Z\s-]|\\')+$
```

http://regexr.com/3g7dm

Note: If you're doing this to protect your SQL queries, it's not the proper way.  You should be using prepared statements.